# Is there a way to create a box of asterisks around a SAS comment?

Tags: sas, comments

I was wondering if there was a way to quickly create a box around a comment in SAS.  Currently you can use a command Ctrl + Shift + / to create comments such as this

```
/*This is a comment*/
/*This is the second line of the comment*/
```

I would like to know if anyone has a solution to box in multiple lines of comments, like this:

```
/******************************************/
/* This is a comment                      */
/* This is the second line of the comment */
/******************************************/
```

Currently the only way I know how to create boxes like this is to manually type in asterisks and add spaces until the code lines up.  I'm hoping there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/samkart/SASUtilityMacros/blob/master/SAS_File_Headers%20macro.sas) might come in handy. I wrote this piece a while back for my day to day codes. Change to suit your needs.

Comment: Just to be sure, this code only creates a header, correct?

Comment: I've made a macro to automatically generate a header for me in the log and I use that to copy/paste in the program. You could do something similar that has a fixed width for comments. It would be somewhat tedious as you would need to decide if a word is too long for the rest of the line, but it's definitely doable.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will create the comment box in the log. You can then copy and paste it into your code.

It uses '/' as the default delimiter to split the lines.  But this can be changed when calling the macro, as shown below.

```
%macro comment_box(comment, delimiter='/');
    /* count the number of line using the delimiter */ 
    %let line_count = %sysevalf(%sysfunc(countc(%str(&comment.), &delimiter.)) + 1);
    %let max_line_len = 0;
    /* loop through to split the text into lines measure the line length including leading&trailing blanks */
    %do x=1 %to &line_count.;
        %let line&x. = %scan(%str(&comment.), &x., &delimiter.);
        %let line&x._len = %sysevalf(%length(%str(&&line&x..)) + 2);
        %if &&line&x._len. > &max_line_len. %then %let max_line_len = &&line&x._len.;
    %end;

    /* Create the top/bottom box line matching to the max text line length */
    /* Add the comment box to the log using PUT statements. */
    option nonotes;
    data _null_;
        line_count = &line_count.;
        max_line_len = &max_line_len.;
        box_line = cat('/*', repeat('*', max_line_len - 1), '*/');
        %do x=1 %to &line_count.;
            %if &max_line_len. = &&line&x._len. %then %do;
                line&x. = cat('/* ', "&&line&x..", ' */');
            %end;
            %else %do;
                line&x. = cat('/* ', "&&line&x..", repeat(' ', %sysevalf(&max_line_len. - &&line&x._len. - 1)), ' */');
            %end;
        %end;
        /* add the comment box to the log */
        put box_line;
        %do x=1 %to &line_count.;
            put line&x.;
        %end;
        put box_line;
    run;
    option notes;
%mEnd;


%comment_box(%str(This is a comment/This is the second line of the comment));
%comment_box(%str(This is a comment+This is the second line of the comment), delimiter= '+');
```

Comment: This works well, except that it breaks if your comment contains quotations.

Comment: If you recode the steps done in the data_null_ to macro lines using %sysfunc, you will be able to to handle comment with quotations using %bquote.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using enterprise guide, have you tried using the keyboard macro section?

[image]

#### Example

This is a very quick one that just inserts a `/*****/` of a set length but there might be enough functionality in there to correctly set the length of this by the length of your comment.

[image]

You can then assign it to a key combination.

[image]